# Django Populate ManyToManyField overriding save method

Tags: django, django-models

When i create a `Mess` also it requires to fill the `admin` field and i do it always.

I want, when i create a Mess, the `members` field of the mess should populate automatically  with the `admin`

Here you go for my admin:

```
class Mess(models.Model):
    alias = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid4,
        editable=False
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    admin = models.OneToOneField(
        Person,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='mess_admin'
    )
    members = models.ManyToManyField(
        Person,
        related_name='mess_members',
        blank=True,
    )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.admin not in self.members_set.all():
            self.members.add(self.admin)
        super(Mess, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I want overriding save method, I want to add the admin to `members` field too but I don't to populate it manually, it will add the admin of the mess and the same admin will be in `members` field too.

Can anyone help me to achive this? My current `save` method is not working following my requirement.

this is the errors it throws:

```
AttributeError at /admin/mess/mess/add/
'Mess' object has no attribute 'members_set'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "... is not working"? Please explain in more detail and add any errors (full error stacktrace) that you are getting.

Comment: AttributeError at /admin/mess/mess/add/
'Mess' object has no attribute 'members_set'

Answer (score 1):

In your model you define the field as `members`, not `members_set`:

```
class Mess(models.Model):
    ...
    members = models.ManyToManyField(...)
    ...
```

I also suggest using `.filter()` and `.exists()` instead of `not in` to test for membership:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.members.filter(pk=self.admin.pk).exists():
    ...
```

---

Have you tried saving first and then adding to `members`? In that case the call to `super()` comes first:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    if not self.members.filter(pk=self.admin.pk).exists():
        self.members.add(self.admin)
```

Comment: Mess' object has no attribute 'mess_members'

Comment: I tied with this too, it doesnt work Mess' object has no attribute 'mess_members'

Comment: @BayonSharke I edited my answer; I think it should be `members` instead of `members_set`.

Comment: Currently, it is not showing any error but not pupulating members field

Comment: @BayonSharke I edited my answer; Have you tried saving first and then adding to `members`?

Answer (score 1):

```py
class Mess(models.Model):
    ...
    admin = models.OneToOneField(
        Person,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='mess_admin'
    )
    members = models.ManyToManyField(
        Person,
        related_name='mess_members',
        blank=True,
    )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Mess, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.members.filter(pk=self.admin.id).count() == 0:
            self.members.add(self.admin)
```

should do the trick.

Explanation:
1) As mentioned by @Ralf, you have the property `members` and not `members_set`.
2) Save first, then see if your model still needs an update

Comment: I guess, you didnt check.. It is not pupulating the members field even it is not showing error

Comment: Can you provide a small example showing your issue ?

Comment: It is not showing any error, how  can i show you example? Problem only, Members field are not pupulating

Comment: What I mean is: provide a minimal Django project with this model and the way you access/save it, so I can test just as you do ;)